# Is this an OK question for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If not, is there another Stack Exchange site where it would be a better fit?

CSS, as we know, stands for Cascading Style Sheets, which is a plural phrase. One would say "Cascading Style Sheets are used to provide a central location for all of the stylings of a project" (note the 'are'). However, it seems to be the prevalent usage to say "CSS *is* used to provide a central location for all of the stylings of a project" (singular). Why do we do this, and is this correct?

(I realize I used this form in the first sentence, but that was referring to the acronym itself, not Cascading Style Sheets)

**Update:** This question has been posted [at EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/40007/11762).

Comment: How about [english.se]?

Comment: I thought english.SE might be best, but since it seemed pretty specific to programming, I thought maybe here or programmers.SE might be acceptable, and probably provide a more relevant answer, as the people using SO and P.SE are the people using the terms in my question.

Comment: As long as you provide some basic explanation of what CSS means, as you did in your example, this should be perfectly answerable by the people at english.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a question for [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com).

The [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) reports the following text:

> The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts. Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:
>
> - Usage, word choice, and grammar
> - Etymology (history of words’ development)
> - Dialect differences
> - Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Problems encountered by people learning English
>
> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - Please proofread my document ("are there any mistakes in this text?")
> - Languages other than English (including translation)
> - How to improve my English
> - How to name this function/variable in my program
> - Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature
> - Peeving about grammar disguised as a question
> - "Explain this joke to me", except in the case where the crux of the joke relies on an aspect of English covered by one of the welcomed topics above.

Comment: *Sidenote:* There have been questions about programming specific language questions on Meta.English: [Could we add tags for domain-specific language questions, such as programming?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/406) [Is Python a snake or a programming language? If the latter, why is it choking my dog?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/) Those are providing some guidelines for such questions.

Comment: The second question you linked is the reason why the FAQ reports "How to name this function/variable in my program" as question you should not ask on EL&U.

Answer (score 9):

No, this is off-topic on Stack Overflow; it's a question about grammar and language. [Let's make the FAQ-Test](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

- **a specific programming problem:** No
- **a software algorithm:** No
- **software tools commonly used by programmers:** Nope
- **matters that are unique to the programming profession:** Naaahhhh...

That's 0 out of 4.